# RestSharp send proper value with header

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please check the RestSharp code bellow. I am passing AddHeader correctly however i am getting response saying i am not passing Content-Type header correctly. How can i fix this issue any idea? Note: api documentation [details here.](http://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3)  Also checkout debug response screen shot bellow [image: pic]

```
static void Test()
  {

      var client = new RestClient("https://api.getresponse.com/v3");
      var request = new RestRequest();
      request.Method = Method.POST;
      request.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
      request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Token:", " api-key my-key-here");
      request.Parameters.Clear();
      var response = client.Execute(request);


  }
```

Comment: Your RestSharp code is correct, this means the problem is with `api.getresponse.com` handling. I would check you're sending them the correct API key per your username.

Comment: Yes. i am sending correct api key. Do you want to try it then i can share with you as test purpose? And doc doesn't says anything about other stuff like Username or password

Comment: You also not sending any resource to extract e.g: `https://api.getresponse.com/v3/accounts`

Comment: Well. I just wanted to pass from bad request. Once this work i will adjust other things as my need.